# hook_node_load doesn't work when node is loaded by REST api

Tags: 7, nodes

On the web, everything works fine (and I even checked the node values with krumo), when I tried fetching the json equivalent of the node using *REST api*, it's as if the `hook_node_load()` didn't run.

If in case you are curious what does my `hook_node_load()` function do, it manipulates a custom field value(that was initially saved) and change it into equivalent value from my custom database table
***tl;dr*** - *I changed the value of a field*

I would like some *help/tips/guide* in anyway how can I execute my hook function so I can manipulate the data outputs given from *REST api*.

ps: I just started with drupal a month ago, if by chance I am approaching this the wrong way and should be using other hook function instead, please  tell me.

Thank you